# How to run ffmpeg to record a virtual screen from a different docker container

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I using 2 docker containers to manage my application, one of them is for the application itself and it's rendered on a virtual screen using XVFB and the another one have ffmpeg which supposed to record this screen, so I managed to get them work together if both the application and ffmpeg on the same docker container but don't know how to do it if they're on a different docker containers.

so in main container I run

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen +extension RANDR -1920x1080x24 -nolisten tcp &
```

and on the ffmpeg container I run

```
ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :99+100,200 output.mp4
```

I tried to change the host to `application_container_name:99+100,200` and tried to use the ip address of the maintain application like `172.17.0.2:99+100,200` but both didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are able to access the x11 port of `container_1` from the `FFmpeg` container
if it is `accessible`
then in the `FFmpeg` container, you can start

```
ffmpeg -y -f x11grab -video_size 1360x1020 -r 15 -i ${host}:${DISPLAY_NUM}.0 -codec:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p record1.mp4
```

Here `${host}` is your `container_1` name
`${DISPLAY_NUM}` is the display of `container_1`
To validate it, in `container_1` run `echo $DISPLAY`